# Cannot create an instance of the abstract class or interface 'Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.WindowsAzure.TransientFaultHandling.RetryManager'

Tags: asp.net, sql, azure

I am just trying to retry logic for transient failures in azure here is my code i am getting this error.

```
Cannot create an instance of the abstract class or interface 'Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.WindowsAzure.TransientFaultHandling.RetryManager'
```

Help me width this

```
        const string defaultRetryStrategyName = "fixed";
        const int retryCount = 10;
        var retryIntervel = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3);
        var strategy = new FixedInterval(defaultRetryStrategyName, retryCount, retryIntervel);
        var strategies = new List<RetryStrategy> { strategy };
        var manager = new RetryManager(strategies, defaultRetryStrategyName);
        RetryManager.SetDefault(manager);
```

Comment: That's right, you cannot "Cannot create an instance of the abstract class or interface "

Comment: ya i know but is there any other way that i could achieve that?

Comment: @Vivekh - remove references to old libraries and add reference to Enterprise Library 6. I would recommend reading this first: [Enterprise Library 6](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/dn169621.aspx).